# Laravel Sanctum : column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'api_token' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sanctum

package: Sanctum

After generate token when request for get data its throw me error like this

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'api_token' in   
'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `api_token` = XAzuNGUeOJ8CXbIoGEWhBTtWIFr0lFr8jjwScXQ4B0Qxfmu
2cHm9LaUwGX96zy0AnXhLLcCnBFCodQaOlimit 1) in file
```

Comment: Does the `api_token` column exist on the users table?

Comment: Perhaps forgot a migration?

Comment: the same bug, did you resolve issue?

Comment: import EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful in kernel.php for token verification.  use Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStatefulin api section

Comment: did you resolve this issue? @Parthkharecha

Comment: @hakiko Yes check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/65472868/9077019

Answer (score 27):

go to config/auth.php

and change the api array in guards to sanctum
example:

```
 'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'sanctum',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: Yeah indeed. Nice that they put this in their documentation. Wasted a few hours on this.

Comment: It did not solve my problem. I clear every cache. I'm using v8 :(

Comment: Thanks! In the latest laravel version, they have removed the API guard as default.  Thanks, it works. 

```php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache```

Answer (score 7):

Go to `routes/api.php` and use this

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

instead of

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

In the api.php

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

In the config/auth.php

```
'api' => [
    'driver' => 'sanctum',
    'provider' => 'users',
    'hash' => false,
],
```

After that, it will fix the issue. I have uploaded the code to my GitHub.https://github.com/ramseyjiang/laravel_8_api

Comment: While this code may answer the question, adding some explanation on how and why it solves it will improve the quality of your answer

Comment: @ᴄʀᴏᴢᴇᴛ you need to make sure that the `api -> driver` is set to *sanctum*

Answer (score 1):

import `EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful` in *kernel.php* for token verification

```
use Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{

    'api' => [
               ------
               EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
               ------
             ],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had messed with the `config\sanctum.php` file. Specifically I had changed the guard to `'guard' => ['api'],`.

reverting to `'guard' => ['web'],` fixed it. Not sure why I changed it in the first place tbh.

Answer (score 0):

Run the migration and then check, if there was still the issue then either `users` table don't have `api_token` field or it's not defined in the `User` model inside `$fillable` array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try add "middleware(auth:sanctum)" for your api route.

Example:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('products', function() {
      //code
})->name('api.products');
```

Answer (score 0):

Run

1. php artisan cache:clear
2. php artisan config:clear
3. php artisan route:clear

Then restart Apache and Mysql (for XAMPP/WAMPP) and run *artisan serve command* again
it worked for me.make sure you read their docs first

Comment: This is a typical cache clearing method, but how does it help solve the problem posed?

Answer (score 0):

1.So to answer this question, after racking my brain, I decided to clear the application, configuration, and route caches,that did the trick for me.

```
  php artisan cache:clear
```

2.You can run the above statement in your console when you wish to clear the application cache. What it does is that this statement clears all caches inside storage\framework\cache.

```
  php artisan route:cache
```

3.This clears your route cache. So if you have added a new route or have changed a route controller or action you can use this one to reload the same.

```
  php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

- First drop table **personal_access_tokens**
- Second delete row that contain "%create_personal_access_tokens_table%" in your table migrations.
- Third execute again **php artisan migrate**.