# Laravel sanctum looking for api_token column

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sanctum

When I try to get my user by api token it return this error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'api_token' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `api_token` = 2|eCk2vQOmH1RqSzjP8WF6tlQIILHkMblEQVMnyC9l and `users`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1)
```

But there is no `api_token` column in users table, tokens are storing in `oauth_access_tokens` table why it's looking in `users` table for them?!

How I try to get my user?

```
public function index(Request $request) {
    $user = $request->user();
    return response()->json($user);
}
```

## Code

`kernel`

```
'api' => [
    EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
    'throttle:60,1',
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
],
```

`route`

```
Route::get('schools', 'Api\SchoolsController@index')->middleware(['auth:sanctum']);
```

**Any idea?**

## Update

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        // 'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
    }
}
```

## Update 2

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'sellers' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'sellers',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'sellers' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Seller::class,
        ], 

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
        'sellers' => [
            'provider' => 'sellers',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
    | times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
    | confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
    |
    */

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

Comment: What does your authserviceprovider look like?

Comment: @James updated.

Comment: @James anything?

Comment: Sorry your auth.php file

Comment: @James updated.

Comment: @James are you going to say anything?

Comment: you can check that answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61141197/laravel-sanctum-column-not-found-1054-unknown-column-api-token-in-where-cl/63302055#63302055

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Sanctum : column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'api\_token' in 'where clause'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61141197/laravel-sanctum-column-not-found-1054-unknown-column-api-token-in-where-cl)

Comment: Are you using `auth:api` anywhere by accident?